# How to close USSD alert dialog programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, operators, ussd

I am building an Android application where I am dialling an USSD code using network operator.

I have use below code. It's working for all operator USSD message but not working with the Vodafone operator.

```
  Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
  sendBroadcast(closeDialog);

  performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
```

Vodafone USSD message screenshot:

[image: Vodafone USSD message screenshot]

Comment: Is this Android itself ? The screenshot looks like an iOS UI

Comment: Yes, It's android. The phone model is MI note